# transparent drawing software

Tags: video-editor, video-recording, screen-casting

I want to ask if there's a software that I could pint on it with my graphics tablet where I draw on it but it has no background!!
Actually, the case that I want to make some tutorials that I need to draw or write some texts live over some pdf, slides or even some running applications.
The now way is to print screen then go and write over it on a drawing software and finally append it to my video with the voice explanation.

What I want is to run my pdf, slides or any local or web app and start a software that makes my screen as a board but transparent so while recording my screen I could write over on anywhere with my graphics tablet.

Comment: Not 100% sure that I understand your question, but if you're after software that lets you paint over other applications, try alchemy: http://al.chemy.org/